# Sending email with image attachment

Tags: android, share, email-attachments

I need to send an email using the Android share intent with an image that needs to be fetched using a network request.

Most of the examples I've found of doing this involve images that have already been saved to the device.

How can i achieve this if the image needs to be fetched first, without necessarily saving it to disk?

I am using Glide as my image loader.

Comment: You first should download the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can save image in to cache directory using glide and send it as an attachment  by using following code

```
   Glide
.with(getApplicationContext())
.load("https://www.google.es/images/srpr/logo11w.png") // your URL
.asBitmap()
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
     File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);// use your filename fully
    f.createNewFile();
    //Convert bitmap to byte array
    Bitmap bitmap = resource;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
    byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
    //write the bytes in file
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fos.write(bitmapdata);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    Uri U = Uri.fromFile(f);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("image/png");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, U);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Email:"));  
     }
});
```

Comment: `f.createNewFile();`. You can remove that statement as it is of no use and only confusing. Further you should do away with the byte array output stream and compress to the file output stream directly.

Comment: For the rest this code converts a downloaded png file to a bitmap and then converts that bitmap back to a png file. That is bad programming.